# How to develop an UDP port scanner? It is not working very well

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#####################################
# Portscan UDP        #
# #
#####################################
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#!/usr/bin/python3
import socket

ip = (input("Type IP or Address: "))

ports = []
count = 0

while count < 5:
    ports.append(int(input("Type the port: ")))
    count += 1


for port in ports:
    client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    client.bind((ip, port))
    msg = 'hi'
    client.sendto(msg.encode(), (ip,port))
    data, address = client.recvfrom(1024)
    #print("Recebida ->", str(data))




    if data != None:
         print (str(port) + " -> Port is opened")
    else:
         print (str(port) + " -> Port is closed")

print ("Scan Finished")
```

I am trying to develop an UDP port scanner in python 3. I know UDP is connectionless, so I sent a message and if the destination reply,port is opened. Otherwise, port may be filtred.
My code always shows : "port is opened". Could someone help me?

Comment: Even if a UDP service is listening at the remote port, there's no guarantee you're going to receive any data back.  And even if it does send a response, there's no guarantee it's going to use the same port.

Comment: Wait, why are you `bind`ing to the IP & port _you want to scan_?

Comment: I am newbie. Thanks for your helping!

Comment: @ForceBru, I was try to find out if the destination responds...

Comment: @PaulSigonoso, I see, but you normally `bind` to `localhost` to _listen for incoming connections_, not to _connect to anyone else_.

Comment: Thanks for the comment,@ForceBru. Could you correct the code or suggest how finish it?